# Set a system image to NSImageView programatically in Swift

Tags: swift, macos, nsimage, sf-symbols

You can set a system image(SF Symbol) in UIKit with `UIImage(systemName: "pencil")`. For macOS apps you can set a system image in storyboard. However, I couldn't find a way to set a system image for macOS programatically. So is this possible, or is system images limited to storyboard only in macOS Apps.

```
imageView.image = NSImage(named: "pencil") //result is no image
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The call signature is `NSImage(systemSymbolName:accessibilityDescription:)` (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsimage/3622472-init), not `NSImage(named:)`, which tries to get an image from your app bundle -- not SF Symbols.

Example:

```
NSImage(systemSymbolName: "pencil", accessibilityDescription: nil)
```

Note that this is only available in targeting macOS 11.0 (Big Sur) and above. Prior to this, SF Symbols were not available to Mac apps except via Catalyst.

Comment: Most likely added in 12.2, which was the release to accommodate Big Sur.